# Trouble compiling using PS->PDF

Tags: pdf, ps

While compiling a tex file using PS->PDF, I am getting the following error. Please help to understand and resolve it. The file is rps.tex.

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in (rps.ps) Operand stack: Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push Dictionary stack: --dict:1175/1684(

ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:77/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: No such file or directory GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: (1) exactly which programme and version is used for PS -> PDF? (2) which programme made `rps.ps`?

Comment: Ghostscript cannot find the Postscript file `rps.ps` to be converted to PDF. Did you run `dvips rps`?